# Form For Association Comments on Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am trying to create comments that are associated with posts. There are 3 models User, microposts and Comments.
Here are the associations that I have: 
Comment Model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :micropost

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :micropost_id, presence: true
end
```

Microposts Model

```
belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

User Model

```
has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments
```

I have nested the route as:

```
resources :microposts do 
    resources :comments
  end
```

Here is my comment controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment created"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'shared/_comment_form'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment Form:

```
<%= form_for([@micropost, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Write your message.." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

When I run this I get a form I get an argument error, 
***First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty*** 
I am wondering how do I solve this issue? If I just write micropost, @comment it seems to not recognize it either and I get an ***undefined local variable error.***
Why is the comment form not realizing that the micropost is from the comments controller to find the micropost_id?

Comment: do yo you set the values of `@micropost` and `@comment` before this form ?

Comment: `render 'shared/_comment_form', micropost: @micropost`. In your view change the global `@micropost` to local `micropost`.

Comment: I have done the micropost: @micropost  but it still doesn't seem to be working Justin. I will get a undefined local local variable or name error...

Comment: mohammed, i have set the values of micropost in the comments  controller as you can see as well as in the user controller which is @comment = comment.new

Comment: @Jason where is this form ? what is the file ?

Comment: @mohameddiaa27 this form is coming from my app/views/shared/_comments_form.html.erb. Is there some type of miscommunication between the controller and the form?

Comment: i mean where is it rendered ?

Comment: it is rendered in my micropost.

Answer (score 1):

Lets first understand how this form works.

If your resource has associations defined, for example, you want to add comments to the micropost given that the routes are set correctly:

```
<%= form_for([@micropost, @comment]) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

Where `@micropost` and `@comment` are defined before rendering the form.

example: `@micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])` and `@comment = Comment.new`

Later when you submit this form (only on that step) your create action is touched from your comments controller.

so basically what you need to do, is define the `@micropost` and `@comment` before calling the form_for

Comment: is it not defined when i place it under the create method? @micropost and @comment? if so where do i define it?

Comment: in your controller action (where this form appears). To understand what I mean by defining the form. add this line before the form_for.`<% @comment = Comment.new %>`

Comment: so the comment = Comment.new should not be in the user controller correct?

Comment: if the `@micropost and the @comment` appear only once in the page, they can be defined in the controller.